# Formatting type declarations that include many [Attributes] for readability

Tags: delphi, coding-style, attributes

Lately I found myself relying on custom [Attributes] allot. I'm on a quest for creating RTTI and Generics based variants of the VCL controls I most often use; My intention is to reduce the amount of boilerplate code to a minimum, and I find RTTI, Anonymous methods and Attributes to be *awesome*.

I've got an unusual problem. Since I end up using lots of [Attributes], I need a **readable** way to *format* this code. Might sound like an insignificant problem but I'm very obsessive with my formatting and indenting. The problem with attributes is that they're not formatted in a special way by the IDE. In a block of multiple field declarations, inter-wind with [Attribute] declarations, you'd have a hard time guessing what's a type, what's an attribute, what attribute applies to what field. Here's a minimal example:

```
type
  [OneAttribute('SomeParam', 7), AnOtherAttribute]
  TSomething = class
  public
    [OneAttribute('SomeParam', 7), AnOtherAttribute]
    FieldName: string;
    [OneAttribute('SomeParam', 7), AnOtherAttribute]
    OtherField: Integer;
    [OneAttribute('SomeParam', 7), AnOtherAttribute]
    function Sum(a,b:Integer):Currency;
    [OneAttribute('SomeParam', 7), AnOtherAttribute]
    property Name:string read FieldName write FieldName;
  end;
```

The way I formated those [Attributes] in the example above is the way most often seen in `C#` code; Unfortunately I have seen no example of Delphi code using attributes, except my own. This works slightly better for `C#` because you're less likely to apply attributes to actual fields and more likely to apply them to `properties` or `functions`; Since in `C#` the function implementation immediately follows it's declaration (the same for properties) you don't get the same kind of block as with Delphi; functions and property declarations are naturally separated so glancing over the code is not hindered by the use of attributes.

I tried the obvious source for delphi-related "style" information. The code formater in Delphi 2010 doesn't understand property declarations at all! In the above example, if I remove the `public` keyword and run the built-in code formater then the first line of Attributes declarations is moved one line up behind the `class` keyword as if it's declaring an ancestor class.

I grepped around the Delphi 2010 source code. Either my grep-fu is failing me badly or there's absolutely no use of attributes in the whole of the Delphi 2010 sources. Just to be clear, after trying to grep for the actual uses of attributes (difficult because square brackets are used allot and they rarely mean it's an attribute declaration) I started grepping for `TCustomAttribute`: there's no descendant of `TCustomAttribute` anywhere, so obviously there's no use of attributes.

Finaly to the question:

## How do you format [Attributes] for readability?

My latest solution looks like this:

```
type
 [OneAttribute('SomeParam', 7), AnOtherAttribute]
  TSomething = class
  public
   [OneAttribute('SomeParam', 7), AnOtherAttribute]
    FieldName: string;
   [OneAttribute('SomeParam', 7), AnOtherAttribute]
    OtherField: Integer;
   [OneAttribute('SomeParam', 7), AnOtherAttribute]
    function Sum(a,b:Integer):Currency;
   [OneAttribute('SomeParam', 7), AnOtherAttribute]
    property Name:string read FieldName write FieldName;
  end;
```

I'm normally using two-column indent; For attributes I'm thinking of moving the attribute declaration one-to-the-left; There's always space for that since my types, fields, methods and properties always have a minimum of 2 columns right-indent (for types) or 4 for class members. Left-indenting like *seems* to blend nicely with existing declarations that do not use attributes, and I want the attributes to "stand out", so left indent is better then right indent.

What do you think? Have you got better ideas?

Comment: I use the first version and just add blank lines after each. And optionally two blank lines after a group of those attribute/method-property pairs for "functional separation". Needs more screen real estate, but it helps...

Comment: @MarjanVenema, thank you, I also did that but I'm not very happy with it because it's so sparse. Not only wastes screen space but also dilutes information. It's an option those, and maybe a better standard then my option. Maybe you'd consider posting this as an answer so I can vote it up. I guess I'd also like to get the a sense of the community's preference: other people need to read (and write) code using whatever standard I'm going to select, I don't want to make this just about *me*.

Comment: Isn't this a perfect fit for "not constructive" close votes?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: maybe, as it sollicites opinion, but it is very specific.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

An answer as per request.

I use the first version and just add blank lines after each. And optionally two blank lines after a group of those attribute/method-property pairs for "functional separation". I have also been known to repeat the visibility specifier to separate functional groups of methods/properties.

It needs more screen real estate, but it helps..

```
type
  [OneAttribute('SomeParam', 7), AnOtherAttribute]
  TSomething = class
  public
    [OneAttribute('SomeParam', 7), AnOtherAttribute]
    FieldName: string;

    [OneAttribute('SomeParam', 7), AnOtherAttribute]
    OtherField: Integer;

    [OneAttribute('SomeParam', 7), AnOtherAttribute]
    function Sum(a,b:Integer):Currency;

    [OneAttribute('SomeParam', 7), AnOtherAttribute]
    property Name:string read FieldName write FieldName;

  public
    [OneAttribute('SomeParam', 7), AnOtherAttribute]
    TableName: string;

    [OneAttribute('SomeParam', 7), AnOtherAttribute]
    OtherTable: Integer;

    [OneAttribute('SomeParam', 7), AnOtherAttribute]
    function TableSum(a,b:Integer):Currency;
  end;
```

Comment: +1, it's an option. I especially like the two `public` sections, I end up doing that allot (mostly in the `private` area). My issue with this solution is that it's very sparse and dilutes content. When you have 5 type declarations one after the other, with many-many fields, it all gets a little blurry.

Comment: @CosminPrund: yes that is my peeve with it as well, but I haven't as yet found another way. Your second version is an option as well, but is a little too "jumpy" (with regard to indentation) for me.

Comment: @MarjanVenema, I wish the IDE would color the Attribute declarations in some other way; Like the compilere-directives are colored distinctly from comments. That would really help.

Comment: @CosminPrund: Yeah, that's one I would like too, along side a whole pile of other IDE productivity / usability issues. Wish EMBA would focus on developer productivity with IDE enhancements instead of just adding RAD frameworks or platforms.

Comment: @StefanGlienke, why each attribute on a separate line? I always put related attributes in a single `[...]`, I find it easier to read that way.

Comment: @CosminPrund Same reason I don't put fields with the same type into one line: personal preference. I find it easier to not have to read through the whole line because some attribute might be there

Comment: @StefanGlienke, I also don't put multiple fields of the same type on a single line, but attributes are different: they all apply to the next declaration, they're not independent in the way fields are. And in fact some of them are logically related and might not even make sense all by themselves. I'm not judging your preference, I just want to know if there's more to it then just personal preference.